# Android Webview SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, webview, refresh

Is it possible to refresh `WebView` current page using `SwipeRefreshLayout`? If it is can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `webview` inside SwipeRefreshLayout and override the `onRefresh()` method of SwipeRefreshLayout.

In onRefresh() method you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Making that, I am unable to scroll down  my webview